# Android download mp3 file and play it

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to download some audio files from Dropbox to be used by the user a next time without internet, so the code actually downloads the file but i'm having troubles to play that audio, i don't know if i have to parse the downloaded file or something, hope you can help

Download file and play it class, it play it on the post execute or at least it tries

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/workout.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            Uri u = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/workout.mp3");

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/workout.mp3");
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

im actually getting this error on the log

```
05-31 11:46:11.605 4638-4650/com.example.project.calisthenic E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

the problem is trying to play the downloaded file, even if a try to play it with the android native player it says "The player doesn't support this type of audio file", so i don't know if i'm downloading the file in the wrong way o trying to play it in the wrong way.

I'd check and the file size is 10kb and after downloading it is 400B so definitely have to be something wrong with the download

Comment: what trouble you are facing ? pl post the log if you are getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem come from it but you should set prepare listener before calling prepare function.

Comment: already try that, the problem comes from the download, because a 10kb file it download it in 400b, that's not possible, so i guess it a corrupted download